# How to get dimensions of Excel worksheet in perl?

Tags: perl, spreadsheet

I need to find how many rows in worksheet have been defined. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel)'s `row_range` method.

Comment: What does Max and min? I didnt get. There should be only one value.

Comment: @Shubham, nobody forces you to put anything in row 1.  `row_range` tells you both the first and last row that were actually used.

Comment: Spreadsheet::ParseExcel only handles xls files; for xlsx, use Spreadsheet::XLSX